# Programatically transfer files from any CDN to Google Cloud bucket

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I would like to transfer a bunch of files that lives on a CDN to my Google Cloud bucket. I have **no control over the CDN** and cannot access anything on it except the files I would like to transfer. Any idea if the Google Cloud Storage API have any support for this kind of action?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer myself, the Google Cloud Transfer Service does support regular HTTP data sources as you can see here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/TransferSpec